# Display TOTAL number of registered users on index.html

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

routes.py:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(name=form.name.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login', 'success')
        return redirect('login')
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

Models:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.name}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

HTML:

```
<h2 class="sub-title">find awesome people like you</h2>
<div id="incremental-counter" **data-value="12"**></div>
<p>People Already Signed Up</p>
```

I'm trying to display the number of registered users stored in the id row of the User table. I've tried a few different things with no luck. Frustrating. Your help is much appreciated!

[Here's a photo of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGB6u.png)

Comment: Have you tried this: `db.session.query(User).count()`?

Comment: That did it. I set it to a variable of user_id, {{ user_id }} in the HTML in the data-value, and Voilà! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to bernie for the layup answer here:

In my routes.py:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    user_id = db.session.query(User).count()
#.....
```

In my HTML:

```
<div id="incremental-counter" data-value="{{ user_id }}"></div>
```

Thanks again Bernie!